# Edit "last used location"

Tags: excel

When I run Excel then I have new workbook opened. When I click on save(as) or open then dialog is invoked in "Default file location". But after any open/save action is done then "Default file location" is no more used. Open dialog is invoked into last used location (either by open or save dialog). Save dialog is invoked into "Path" (location of workbook -where it is saved) and if "Path" doesn't exist then last used location is used as well.

My question is how can I find out and override the last used location?

Only way which come to my mind is to override WorkbookBeforeSaveEvent somehow, but it is not solution since WorkbookBeforeOpenEvent doesn't exists. I would need somehow to get from Excel last used location (used by open or save dialog) and somehow set it as I need. Solution should work in Excel 2007 - 2013. Any advice?

Why I need it is that I am opening some add-in (inside my adding when it is started) and then first invoke of open/save dialog is in ugly path. Then I need occasionally save some dummy file in temp... Then Again I have ugly path.

Any possible solution is good for me it can be in VBA, via COM, xll sdk or maybe in VSTO (not preferred).

Comment: Maybe save a blank file to the desired default location and then delete it?

Comment: Well that could be a solution, but there are two things I don’t like about it: 1) It is obviously just some kind of workaround. 2) In case that I want keep location where I just opened some file, then I cannot be sure that I will have rights to write and delete files in that location.

Comment: I can't help you with the workaround part, but if you can't find a solution another idea would be to reopen the previous file and then close it.

Comment: Thanks, that is actually good idea. I don't see any more reasons why it shoudn't work. But still it is not very nice create/delete or open/close file, I would rather to find better solution.

Comment: We used to be able to do that in XP -- there was a registry location. But MS removed it in later versions. Perhaps you could store your desired location in the registry, and then recall it when you are ready to do your Save.

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld: Since I cannot set path which would Excel use I don't see a way how it could help me...

Comment: @Sekory Perhaps I'm not understanding you.  But take a look at Application.GetSaveAsFilename.  That allows you to bring up a dialog box with the selected path. e.g: Application.GetSaveAsFilename "D:\" would bring up the SaveAs dialog box with D:\ as the "root" folder.

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld: I probably didn't really explain myself very well. I was able to open open/save dialog programmatically in any path. My problem was that when user invoke open/save dialog via UI then there is ugly path. But I actually find a solution (it is here as answer now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for solution in Excel all the time. And that was my biggest mistake. Because there is no solution in Excel. Excel don't really change the "last used path". Solution is just SetCurrentDirectory: 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I did it via com in C# and it working as is needed.